# vscode terminal gets stuck and doesnt show the folder path

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, parceljs, vscode-tasks

In my vscode as soon as my react app get build(using parcel as bundler) the path in the terminal gets lost. For giving a new command i have to restart my Vscode

i restart my vscode everytime i have to add some new command in the terminal. I want that it gets resolved in such a way that i dont have to restart it again and again and it shows the path in the terminal as soon as the buikd get completed

Comment: You probably run the parcel in watch mode to update for each file change. Try opening two terminals, press `CTRL+C` to kill the parcel, or run in single build mode. Can you share what command do yu use to run the parcel?

Comment: 'npx parcel index.html ' is the command i used

Comment: now since i have inlcuded it in the script of my package.json file... i just use the command 'npm run start'..where start : 'parcel index.html' in my "scripts" of package.json

Comment: The documentation say all, `Parcel has a development server built in, which will automatically rebuild your app as you make changes. To start it, run the parcel CLI pointing to your entry file: yarn parcel src/index.html"` which from my understanding parcel run development server, if you want to type next command you need to kill the server first.

Comment: If you want to build the project once you need to run `npx parcel build`

Comment: ya it helped ... CTRL+C ...thank you